# Does python's multiprocessing leak memory?

Tags: python, memory-leaks, multiprocessing

I've narrowed down a piece of code to the following minimal (working?) example:

```
import multiprocessing

def f(x): return x**2

for n in xrange(2000):
    P = multiprocessing.Pool()
    sol = list(P.imap(f, range(20)))
```

When I run this on my computer (Ubuntu 12.04, 8-core), python proceeds to consume all available memory and eventually it hangs the system due to an unresponsive swap. I've heard that Python doesn't release memory until it's finished, but I think it's a bit silly that this program should consume over 8Gb of RAM. If I want to create `multiprocessing.Pool` objects over and over, how can I do so without reallocating new memory each time?

Comment: you are trying to launch 2000 process pools, with 8 workers each.
That is 16k processes... not surprised at all you are running out of resources.

Comment: also, Python uses reference counting and garbage collection for memory  dealocation... definitely not: "doesn't release memory until it's finished"

Comment: I'm a little surprised that memory is the problem rather than some other resource, given that linux does CoW fork, so a forkbomb can go far enough to swamp the scheduler or other kernel resources before it gets near thrashing swap…

Comment: As a side note, why would you call `P.imap` just to pass it to `list`? That's just a less efficient way of calling `P.map`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're creating a new multiprocessing pool every loop iteration - don't you only want one pool to which to feed your processing jobs?

```
import multiprocessing

def f(x): return x**2

P = multiprocessing.Pool()
for n in xrange(2000):
    sol = list(P.imap(f, range(20)))
```

Comment: also note that multiprocessing.Pool() creates a pool the size of `cpu_count` if an explicit number of processes is not given.